# My script is very slow while execution. Please tell me what makes this script to provide the result very slow

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Purpose of this script is when i populate Column B cells, Today's date should be populated in column A (only if it is empty). using FOR loop for inserting multiple dates when changing multiples column B cells. I could not bale to identify what makes this script slower. it takes 10 to 15 secs for auto date population. please tweak this to be faster..

```
//------------------------------------------------------------
//Auto-Populate date in Column A of when column B is updated 
//------------------------------------------------------------
function onEdit(event) {
  var eventRange = event.range;
  if (eventRange.getColumn() == 2) { // 2 == column B
    
    // getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
    var columnXRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(eventRange.getRow(), 1, eventRange.getNumRows(), 1);

    var values = columnXRange.getValues();
    
    if (values.length == 1) {        // if active cell is 1, quickly insert date without loop
      values[0][0] = new Date();
    }
    else {
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {       
        if (!values[i][0]) {         // If cell isn't empty
          values[i][0] = new Date();
          //values.clearContent();
        }
        
      }     
    }
    columnXRange.setValues(values);  
  }
}
```

Comment: The script looks to be very inneficient. Why does it's reading the values from `columnXRange`? Anyway, please add a description of the expected result. Includeing some sample input and the corresponding result usually is helpful to undrestand the expected result.

Comment: @Shahul What is the question exactly? Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What is your intended goal with the trigger?

Comment: @Arials : sorry i am new to forum. i have updated the question and the elabrated the code in body. please help me.

Comment: @Shahulhameed One thing that could make it more efficient is to only call `new Date()` once if you don't need minutes and seconds information. Do you need all the information from Date?

Comment: no i don't need minutes and seconds.

Comment: I posted an answer.

Comment: i tried both code suggested below and i still see the delay in inserting date in google sheets. same was i tried in MS Excel and after modifiying the date in B column once i hit enter, date was added. that was very quick.. only thing is VBA macro not supported in android mobiles.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  if (e.range.columnStart == 2) { 
    var columnXRange = e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,e.range.rowEnd-e.range.rowStart + 1,1);
    var values = columnXRange.getValues();
    if (values.length==1) {
      values[0][0]=new Date();
     }else {
      for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {       
        if (!values[i][0]) {
          values[i][0] = new Date();
        }
      }     
    }
    columnXRange.setValues(values);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cooper, i still see the delay in inserting date.

Comment: How large of a delay?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need all the date information being different at each cell, then I would call the Date function once, and store it in a variable for use later. This should speed up your code.

#### Example:

```js
//------------------------------------------------------------
//Auto-Populate date in Column A of when column B is updated 
//------------------------------------------------------------
function onEdit(event) {
  var eventRange = event.range;
  if (eventRange.getColumn() == 2) { // 2 == column B
    
    // getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
    var columnXRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(eventRange.getRow(), 1, eventRange.getNumRows(), 1);

    var values = columnXRange.getValues();
    /* Call Date() just once */
    var date = new Date();
    date = date.toString().split(' ').splice(0,4).join(' ');

    if (values.length == 1) {        // if active cell is 1, quickly insert date without loop
      values[0][0] = date;
    }
    else {
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {       
        if (!values[i][0]) {         // If cell isn't empty
          values[i][0] = date;
        }
        
      }     
    }
    columnXRange.setValues(values);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Aerials, i still see the delay in inserting date.

Comment: @Shahulhameed we can't reproduce the speed at which your function executes. You could time the execution of the function to try testing. And also how many rows does your sheets have to put the date into?

Comment: i see 3 seconds delay.. i just made copy of that document.. below is the link. please try yourself once.. and help me if possible

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cYRVIO_djvXfSjzJ2xv4Fv7lqLYqLl0F-AYLMSy3M10/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I tested the script. I would say that is normal execution time.